# Bug in ClusteringComponents yielding different results on practically same input?

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis

I am using the image below.

[image: noisy test image]

I want to run a simple `ClusteringComponents`, using the `KMeans` method and `EuclideanDistance` `DistanceFunction`. Just to make sure there is no problem with the implementation of `ClusteringComponents` with images, I use the data of the Image and operate on the second level of the list obtained via `ImageData`. So my call to `ClusteringComponents` looks like this:

```
ClusteringComponents[
  ImageData[ImageResize[image, 500, Resampling -> "NearestLeft"]], 4, 
  2, Method -> "KMeans", 
  DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance] // Colorize
```

with `image` being the image below and the `ImageResize` is just here for reference, because the resolution in x-direction should already be 500. The result is not what I expect and what it should be when using `EuclideanDistance`:

[image: output1]

And here comes the surprising right result: As the `KMeans`-algorithm should be invariant under duplication operation, i.e. just instering every entry multiple times, the following code (which is due to `ImageResize` with `Resampling->"NearestLeft"` just inserting every entry 4 times) should give the same result as the code before just with twice the resolution:

```
ClusteringComponents[
  ImageData[ImageResize[image, 1000, Resampling -> "NearestLeft"]], 4, 
  2, Method -> "KMeans", 
  DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance] // Colorize
```

Output:
[image: output2]

At least on my Mac (Mac OS X Mavericks, Mathematica 10.0.0) the results are surprisingly not the same, the second piece of code yielding the "right" result, while the first one is not. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: The k-means algorithm can get trapped in a local minimum during optimisation, so try using the `"RandomSeed"` option of `ClusteringComponents` to vary its initial guess. I found that `"RandomSeed" -> 12345` makes the results the same in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Since my above comment appears to have answered the question, I'll upgrade it to an answer.

The k-means algorithm can get trapped in a local minimum during optimisation - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) - so try using the `"RandomSeed"` option of `ClusteringComponents` to vary its initial guess.

For instance, this gives the result that one would expect:

```
image = <your image>;

ClusteringComponents[
  ImageData[ImageResize[image, 500, Resampling -> "NearestLeft"]], 4, 
  2, Method -> "KMeans", DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
  "RandomSeed" -> 12345] // Colorize
```

Comment: Thanks, I am actually feeling a little bit dumb, that I did not think of that myself. Can anyone think of a similar method that does not run into local optimums (I know that `RandomSeed` helps, but it has still a random component in it)?